# What is the best way to create a LinkedIn company Page?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups, linkedin-messages, linkedin-articles

My company has its own LinkedIn Profile and LinkedIn Page. However, it gets messy because people connect with the profile instead of the page. Is this the best option to utilize our company page?

Would it better if I made a brand new company page on my personal LinkedIn account instead?

Please keep in mind that I will need to transfer ownership of the LinkedIn company page after a year.